# convert web page to a pdf with styles

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to convert a web page to PDF including all the styles I've added.
I've used jspdf.js and html2Canvas. But I got only a blur picture in PDF form.
I've searched for many JavaScript codes but didn't find a correct one.

Script I have written is:

```js
function getPDF() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("Image/jpeg");
      //window.open(img);
      var doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'px',
        format: 'a4'
      });
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 440, 627);
      doc.save("download");

    }
  });
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a few things that are contributing.

Your encoder options for the canvas.toDataURL are missing, so you're getting the defaults.  The defaults may be creating a low quality image.  Try this for the highest quality JPEG image:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("Image/jpeg", 1.0);
```

You might also try creating your jsPDF object with measurements, rather than pixels:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");  // jsPDF(orientation, units, format)
```

And when you add the image, scale it to the dimensions of the page:

```
pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 190, 277);  // 190x277 mm @ (10,10)mm
```

See if that gives you a better image quality.

Comment: Thanks Michael...this does not give the size of a4,the image printed is also smaller than the size of pdf,,it can be corrected by changing the dimensions,cant it??

Comment: Yes, you can change the dimensions.  I updated my answer with the correct orientation in the jsPDF constructor ("p" for portrait) and changed the dimensions of the page.  A4 is 210mm X 297mm, and you may need to experiment to get the proper dimensions for your output.

Comment: thanks again..,In my web page there are radio button to be shown.but it does not appear in the image which is printed.does it mean the html@canvas is not taking that values?is there any solutions to be done??

Comment: I believe so, yes.  Some HTML elements might not be rendered with html2canvas.  The documentation lists some, and some circumstances where CSS styling may cause issues, such as with image backgrounds.  There are also known browser issues, so you might try a different browser.  I don't know of any workarounds other than that.

Comment: One suggestion here: [http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/792438/How-to-display-checkbox-and-radiobuttons-and-with](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/792438/How-to-display-checkbox-and-radiobuttons-and-with)

Comment: Thanks a lot  Michael.

Comment: Most recent version of html2canvas claims radio button support: [https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

Comment: sure Michael.the answer will be upvoted.Thanks.one last thing.How could i Print this in two pages.In one page the content is too small.i have found some ways.but those were not worked well.

Comment: There's not a clean way, as far as I know.  I haven't paginated html2canvas before.  Looking at information available, it looks like there might be a few different ways to go about it, but you'd probably have to change your web page a bit.  You might open another question on SO specifically for this, and I think that you'd find answers from people who have done it successfully.